# iOS WKWebView display:none leaves spaces

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, wkwebview

I would like to add specific HTML to hide some contents on my WKWebView.

I'm using this code :

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    NSString *cssString = @"#SITE_HEADER, #comp-imrw5tvg, #WRchTxt0-16wb, #comp-imrvq5jg, #comp-imrv0zgf, #SITE_FOOTERinlineContent, #SITE_FOOTER { display: none;}";
    NSString *javascriptString = @"var style = document.createElement('style'); style.innerHTML = '%@'; document.head.appendChild(style)";
    NSString *javascriptWithCSSString = [NSString stringWithFormat:javascriptString, cssString];
    [webView evaluateJavaScript:javascriptWithCSSString completionHandler:^(id obj, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!webView.isLoading) {
            [self.hud removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }];
}
```

Tried this code too :

```
NSString *scriptString = @"var styleTag = document.createElement(\"style\"); styleTag.textContent = '#SITE_HEADER, #SITE_FOOTER {display:none;}'; document.documentElement.appendChild(styleTag);";
WKUserScript *script = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptString injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentStart forMainFrameOnly:YES];
WKUserContentController *userContentController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
[userContentController addUserScript:script];
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
configuration.userContentController = userContentController;
self.wkWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds configuration:configuration];
```

That hides the correct content, but unfortunately, that leaves a blank space (however, I'm using `display:none`}

How can I achieve this and delete this blank space ?